# Non-retina app download size

Tags: ios, optimization, app-store, retina-display

Let's say we have an universal (iPad/iPhone) app with normal and @2x images. Does a bundle of this app downloaded from the App Store for non-retina iPhone contains @2x and ~ipad resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App from Appstore contain every single resource that developer included. If it supports all devices and you download it using iPhone 3GS - you will download all @2x, @4x as well - but you will never use them.

Same for Universal apps (iPhone, iPad) - you download every single file.

To fix that you need to build your own download manager and put an IPA without resources and download them from web in runtime - pretty popular for games which are resource heavy.

Comment: Imagine case when you download app and return to it (let's say in a bus) without Internet connection You can't use it properly, because of lack of resources?

Comment: Yes - that how it works in some games - most of the however are already forcing you to be online :)

Comment: After digging deeper, I've found that my question was a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611617/do-universal-binaries-contain-all-the-heavy-ipad-graphics-in-the-app-bundle-on-t). The post confirms what you've written. Still, information about download managers was new and very interesting advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "optimized" and "universal"?
 Older, non-retina, non iPhone 5 apps probably did not include @2x resources in their bundles when they were submitted.
 As of now, any app that you submit must have all these mandatory resources, even if you're aiming to target older models. Cheers.

Comment: Optimized as app has not more resources than it's necessary. Universal as iPhone / iPad. "Probably" is not the answer I'm looking for.